# Having better controls of NFT royalties on Elrond blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, nft, multiversx

I am developing an NFT collection with royalties. For the moment, the **royalties** go to my **wallet**, but I want them to be sent to **a smart contract**.

As Elrond developed NFTs, the royalties go to the creator. I didn't find a way to change the creator of an NFT for now.

Do you have any ideas?

Should I mint the NFT a the receiving smart contract?
Can I change the creator of an NFT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Royalties are always sent to the creator of the nft and there is no way to change the creator of the nft later.

So it's always the wallet/smart contract that created the nft originally.

There is ongoing development for an `esdt_nft_create_as_caller` function that will create the nft as the one who was calling the smart contract, but it isn't implemented yet.

Comment: The owner and the creator of the NFT are different things in the Elrond blockchain. The owner is set on the collection and this can be changed. The owner can assign the NFTCreateRole to another account (such as a smart contract), and the designated creator account can mint NFTs in the collection.
Mind the fact that the royalties go to the Creator address and this can't be changed once the NFT was created by a creator. Therefore, the royalties will always go the the address it created that specific NFT and can't be changed after. You can set another creator for next NFTs to be created though.